# How to clean up memory cache for Picasso?

Tags: android, memcached, picasso

I use Picasso for picture viewer, which is able rotate images.
Problem is that when I rotate image and try to update it in viewer, it is not updating until I "destroy" application or use memory policy - `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`. I tried to use app without cache, but it is quite slower, so it is not solution.

Therefore I am looking for the way to clean up image from memory and update view. I can´t use parametr `.rotate(90f)`, because Picasso handle correct rotation by itself, it is not working only temporary until memory is clean up.

This problem is not problem of file cache, it is problem of memory cache (based on my testing with memory cache settings). I also tried to invalidate file cache to be sure, but it didn´t helped as I expected.

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(filePath);

Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(filePath)
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uff, I finally found it. Before I used Glide, which has parametr **signature**. Picasso has something similar called **stableKey**. When I use this, I do not have to care about cache, I just enable it and Picasso handle rest.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(filePath)
.stableKey(uniqueFileAttribute)
.into(imageView);
```